# Now that Django 1.6 uses JSON serialization for sessions instead of pickles, what risks does a leaked SECRET_KEY present?

Tags: django, security

With the old pickle-based sessions, a known SECRET_KEY could lead to privilege escalation/remote code execution exploits. However, with the new JSON session serializer in Django 1.6 this is no longer the case. So what's the worst thing that could happen if someone found my app's SECRET_KEY, assuming I'm running Django 1.6+?

Answer (score 0):

While not as serious as a remote code execution, when using cookie-based sessions the consequences of a forged session are application-specific. For example I might track users to send an email to in the session, and whether I'm allowed to send that email is tracked when I add them, and not at the end; by filling my session with fake data and skipping to the end I could therefore bypass application checks.